# MomentJS format relative date from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, handlebars.js, momentjs

I'm trying to display a date as relative date using momentJS
Currently I'm using express-generator, handlebars as view engine and mongoose to communicate with MongoDB

The data that i get from mongoose is something like :

`2021-08-15T13:44:02.212Z`

which is an ISO date i guess?
but when i render it in handlebars it become something like this :

`Sun Aug 15 2021 20:44:02 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time)`

i tried using **momentJS** relative date but it say **Invalid date**,
how do i fix this ?

Comment: relative time as in , 10 hours ago, 15 mins ago ,etc something like this? Could you show what have you tried?

Comment: i tried using static date moment('2021-08-15T13:44:02.212Z').fromNow() it works, but handlebar render the data as "Sun Aug 15 2021 20:44:02 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time)" so momentJS get dynamically as something like moment("Sun Aug 15 2021 20:44:02 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time)".fromNow() and say its invalid date

Comment: Actually ,  moment( "Sun Aug 15 2021 20:44:02 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time)"
).fromNow() works. It gives `an hour ago`. Check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bas-fg1c2?file=/src/index.js

Comment: My bad , it work but it giving a warning in console "Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format." any idea how to fix it? 

Thank you

Comment: i use this workaround for now moment(new Date(curDate)).format or fromNow etc

Comment: Just  have the format specified, `moment( "Sun Aug 15 2021 20:44:02 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time)",  "ddd MMM D HH:mm:ss" ).fromNow();`